# Enable native android password screen programmatically

Tags: android

Is there a way to enable, disable native android password screen pro-grammatically? I am asking this question because I saw the app [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html) which is capable of enabling and disabling android system password lock programmatically by user interaction without any root privileges. When ever user tries to go into system settings via SureLock app they have enabled native system password screen lock. App also works ics & jb systems without a problem.

Unless is there any alternative ways of implementing similar logic to design custom lock like system password lock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). There is a sample code comes with SDK. First you have to make sure that your application is run above API 2.2 Go to your SDK folder and then samples and then ApiDemos. You can import that project as a sample project. Then go to **com.example.android.apis.app** package and see the **DeviceAdminSample.java** class. That's what you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the KeyguardService to control that.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DISABLE_KEYGUARD

Comment: Thanks Alex. But this does not work like that. Its output depends on what system is currently using for screen lock. If it is pattern lock it may lock the screen using it. What I want is always password lock.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Device Admin APIs for Android**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), you can lock the device, reset and set password restriction also